# Gradle for Java Extension in Visual Studio Code shows the wrong Gradle version

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I installed the Gradle for Java Extension in Visual Studio Code, but I get the following message:

[image]

But I have installed the Gradle version 7.3.3 and linked it in the following Environment variables:

- Path
- GRADLE_HOME
- GRADLE_USER_HOME

When I change the environment variables (Path and JAVA_HOME) to a JDK 11 there is no such error message.

And I set the right path in the settings of the extension, but I always get this error message

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Type `gradle -v` in terminal to check gradle version

Comment: The result of `gradle -v` is Gradle 7.3.3.

Answer (score 3):

Note, the VS Code settings take precedence over the environment variables.

To change the Gradle version of your project, turn to your `current project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`, change the value of `distributionUrl`.

Comment: Yes, with a wrapper I can use whatever version of gradle I want. But for me this seems to be a workaround. I want VS Code to use the latest installed version on my system from the beginning on. Is that possible?

Comment: @tester. Since VS Code settings take precedence over the environment variables and you already add gradle7.3.3 to PATH, you can try deleting related gradle settings in VS Code to make it achieve environment varaibles--> gradle7.3.3 directly.

Comment: How can I dewlete the Gradle Settings in VS Code?

Comment: @tester. Settings.json and build.gradle in your project

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your Gradle v6.4, and your machine work with jdk17.
then you update GRADLE_HOME, then currently Gradle v7.3.3 also updates changes java to jdk11. this not compatible between Gradle and Java.

- Option A, if you'd like to work with Gradle v6.4 then change Java version to jdk14.
- Option B, if you'd like to work with Gradle v7.3.3 then change Java version to jdk17

This reference is compatible between Gradle - JDK, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

.....

Noted

You have configurations that overwrite, after you have compatibility between Gradle and Java, you could work with your machine environment, then you could remove configurations located at .vscode/settings.json that seem like

```
"java.home": "<the path to jdk>",
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "default": true,
        "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
        "path": "<the path to jdk8>",
    }
]
```